# Show that either $f$ or $\bar{f}$ have derivative at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

So the problem here is the following:

If the limit $\lim_{z \to z_0} \left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right| $ exists and is finite, show that  $f$ or $\bar{f}$ has a derivative at $z_0$.

The previous question of the excercise was about the total differential of a complex function and its conjugate. I tried to use it but it didn't help. I would like to give me a small tip and not the whole solution of the excercise if possible!

Edit: The function $f$ has a total differential at the point $z_0$ so it is real differential as well.

Comment: Maybe you could post the "previous question" as well?

Comment: It is a bit overextensive, as it requires me to post the whole previous excercise as well, so that's why I did not. I will try to edit my initial post but that could take a while.

Comment: So, the supposed duplicate has an additional assumption: that $f$ is real-differentiable. Was this omitted from the problem statement?

Comment: @TheoBendit The assumption said that the function had a total differential at a point $z_0$ , so yes I suppose that I should put it in my question because the total differential implies that the function is real differential. Thanks for pointing that out.